# How to select date and previous date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table of referral records with a start date and end date. If the person has had previous referrals I need to retrieve the start and end date of the referral previous to the current one.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Example of what I hope to achieve

```
Per ID    Ref ID    Refrl_Start_D    Refrl_End_D    Prev_Refrl_S    Prev_Refrl_S
1         5         10/10/2018       Null           01/02/2018      03/03/2018
2         4         05/04/2018       Null           01/01/2017      01/03/2017
1         3         01/02/2018       03/03/2018     02/01/2017      20/01/2017
1         2         02/01/2018       20/01/2018     Null            Null
2         1         01/01/2018       01/03/2018     Null            Null
```

Is have tried adding a Rank calc grouped by person. My plan was to create another table offset it by 1 and join them (i.e. Join referral 5 with 4). However I couldn't figure out how to get the join right.

```
SELECT DIM_PERSON_ID,
       FACT_REFERRAL_ID,
       REFRL_START_DTTM,
       REFRL_END_DTTM
FROM FACT_REFERRALS;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) here

```
SELECT DIM_PERSON_ID,
       FACT_REFERRAL_ID,
       REFRL_START_DTTM,
       REFRL_END_DTTM
       PrevStart = LAG(REFRL_START_DTTM)
                       OVER(PARTITION BY DIM_PERSON_ID 
                           ORDER BY REFRL_START_DTTM DESC),
       PrevEnd = LAG(REFRL_END_DTTM)
                     OVER(PARTITION BY DIM_PERSON_ID 
                         ORDER BY REFRL_END_DTTMDESC)
FROM FACT_REFERRALS R;
```

Comment: Hi Mazhar I think this is almost there! I had to change the order by to ASC as it was going backwards. it seems to be working correctly for about 90% of the records however there are some where it is populating a previous start or end date but not the other. Any ideas what my cause this?

Comment: It's hard to say without sample data that can replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to construct this with a CTE to calculate a rank/row number for each record based on the referral dates, then join the CTE to itself to get the previous referral. E.g:

```
WITH RANKED_REFERRALS AS (
  SELECT DIM_PERSON_ID,
         FACT_REFERRAL_ID,
         REFRL_START_DTTM,
         REFRL_END_DTTM,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DIM_PERSON_ID ORDER BY REFRL_START_DATE) AS ROWNUM
  FROM FACT_REFERRALS
)
SELECT A.DIM_PERSON_ID,
       A.ACT_REFERRAL_ID,
       A.REFRL_START_DTTM,
       A.REFRL_END_DTTM,
       B.REFRL_START_DTTM,
       B.REFRL_END_DTTM
FROM RANKED_REFERRALS A
LEFT JOIN RANKED_REFERRALS B ON B.DIM_PERSON_ID = A.DIM_PERSON_ID AND B.ROWNUM = A.ROWNUM - 1
```